# Adding javascript files to WordPress and jQuery version

Tags: php, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I've been trying to use the recommended method of adding javascript files to WordPress, after reading this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script but I'm having a hard time figuring it out...

I've added this to my functions.php:

```
function enqueue_raluk_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tinynav-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/tinynav.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/superfish.js', array('jquery') );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_raluk_scripts' );
```

and after looking inside the source code of my site I can see that they're appearing inside the  tags.

The problem is that those two javascript files require jQuery 1.8.3 to work, and the WordPress built-in jQuery version is newer. How can I go about solving this issue without deregistering (which is a bad practice) the WordPress's default jQuery version? Is there any way to assign a specific jQuery version to be used by certain javascript files? Thanks.

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks. And ideally seperate questions in single problems.

Comment: jQuery is highly backwards compatible, why do you reason two unrelated scripts require precisely old 1.8.3 version? This is likely possible with jQuery's noConflict functionality but as such it's purely JS programming question and better asked at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know they require 1.8.3 because they both work if I use the jQuery 1.8.3 version instead of the default WordPress's 1.10.2 version. Can't I use a custom jQuery version for those two files, and the WordPress's default one for the rest?

Comment: @Rarst : I am having a problem with a script that works on 1.8.3 but not 1.10.2, and I have had trouble with jQuery version changes before. It is not as backward compatible as it might want to be, still this does sound like an [SO] question. DanielSarmas : no, you can't assign a particular jQuery version to a particular script. Take this to [SO] for fixing the scripts but don't use an old jQuery.

Comment: when you say they don't work with newer jQuery, what is the error you receive exactly? are you sure it's not a [noConflict](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) issue? all WordPress jQuery versions are not the same file as the ones available from the jQuery repository, they are modified to be in noConflict mode by default.

Comment: I finally solved it. My superfish() and tinynav() calls were placed inside a separate file, which should have been enqueued after those two scripts. Thank you for your time. :)